# Sympy does not carry out nested sum

Tags: sympy

I am trying to carry out a simple nested sum like this

```
from sympy import *

# Define the symbols
S, T = symbols('S T', integer=True)
s, t, u = symbols('s t u', cls=Idx)
mu = symbols('mu')
a = IndexedBase('a')



S = 1
T = 1

# Define the summand
summand = a[t,u,s]*(-(s+2)*(s+3+2*t))

# Define the outer sum
outer_sum = Sum(Sum(Sum(summand, (u, -t, t)), (t, 0, T)), (s, 0, S))

# Evaluate the nested double sum
result = outer_sum.doit()

pprint(result)
```

The results are just written symbolically like this:

```
1     1     t                                     
 ___   ___   ___                                    
 ╲     ╲     ╲                                      
  ╲     ╲     ╲                                     
  ╱     ╱     ╱    (-s - 2)⋅(s + 2⋅t + 3)⋅a[t, u, s]
 ╱     ╱     ╱                                      
 ‾‾‾   ‾‾‾   ‾‾‾                                    
s = 0 t = 0 u = -t
```

However, I would expect something explicitly of the form coeff1*a[0,0,0] + coeff2*a[1,0,0] + ...
If I am getting rid of the inner sum or change the bounds from -t,t to some numbers it works, but that is not what I need. Is there some way to do this in sympy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it doesn't evaluate but since this the outer sums are finite with numeric limits you can just do it with Python's ordinary `sum` function:

```
In [29]: sum(Sum(summand, (u, -t, t)).subs({t:ti, s:si}).doit() for ti in [0,1] for si in [0,1])
Out[29]: -6⋅a[0, 0, 0] - 12⋅a[0, 0, 1] - 10⋅a[1, -1, 0] - 18⋅a[1, -1, 1] - 10⋅a[1, 0, 0] - 18⋅a[1, 0, 1] - 10⋅a[1, 1, 0] - 18⋅a[1, 1, 1]
```